# Проблемы с переменной в powershell после обновления

Tags: powershell

Обновил posh до 7.1 и некоторые старые скрипты стали работать через одно место, хотя до этого прекрасно выполняли рутину. Например:

```
$login = "username"
Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountNAme -like $login} -Properties mobile
```

Возвращает ошибку

```
Get-ADUser: Variable: 'login' found in expression: $login is not defined.
```

Уже не первый раз сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой, некоторые скрипты пришлось переписывать. Это у них такая обратная "совместимость" или изначально мой г%#нокод.

Answer (score 0):

Немного разобрался, буду копать в эту сторону.
Only ActiveDirectory module from latest version of RSAT Windows Server 2019 works well on PowerShell 7.0